# Node.js, Facebook Graph API - Upload file to facebook using a Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api

I have an application who consist of a Node.js backend hosted on AWS and an Angular 2+ frontend. I am using the facebook graph API on the backend, however, when it comes to uploading things to facebook I'm getting into trouble.

If I want to upload a file, I need to upload it to my backend before, which will put it in an S3 bucket and then upload it from my backend to facebook. This seems to be a little heavy for me and I am really suspicious that it is the correct way to do it. Also, Facebook provides a javascript API that allows us to upload a file from a client to its platform, which seems less heavy.

Right now, I see three solutions:

1. Continue doing everything on the backend
2. Only do upload operations on the client side using the javascript SDK, and everything else on the backend
3. Do everything from the frontend using the javascript SDK

For me, the best solution would be 2. What are your opinions? Is there other solutions?

Comment: How your user authenticate? Do you use Cognito with Facebook as Identity Provider ? Or do you have a single identity on Facebook (the one of your app)

Comment: I'm using Cognito to authenticate to my app and access the backend. The user can connect one or multiple Facebook accounts to make diverse operations on them

Answer (score 0):

If the file is created on the client, there is no need to send it to the server - you can just directly upload it to Facebook instead. Although, if you need to store it on your own server anyway, you can do that first and let the server handle the upload to Facebook - uploading an URL of an image to Facebook is the easiest way. If you don´t need the image on your server, this may help you:

- https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/
- https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-from-canvas/

If the file is on the server already, there is no need to send it to the client before uploading it to Facebook. In that case, i would do the upload server side. If it´s about the security: There is absolutely no problem in sending Access Tokens to the server. You can just use the JS SDK for login, send the Token to the server and do the upload on the server. Just use `appsecret_proof`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/

Comment: Thank you. The files will not be on any server. But then, do you think I should put all the route calls on the front end, or keep only uploads operations on the front and other operations on the backend (like getting the user feed, etc.)?

Comment: that - again - depends. what do you want to do with the user feed, for example? what user feed exactly? do you want to store/cache it? either way, that´s another story, if you only use the image client side, then why would you first push it to the server? that does not make sense to me.

Comment: I use feeds only to retrieve content and reply to comments

Comment: so if you don´t need to store stuff, and if everything can happen on the client only anyway, why bother using the server? just my opinion though.

Comment: I wanted to clearly separate the front end and back end. I also briefly worked in a company who did it this way, but with another API

Comment: well, you will only get opinions, there are different ways to solve things. a clear separation is usually a good thing though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using your end user identity on Facebook there is no benefit to use the backend here (except the fact that you need less Javascript on the page).

**Your user Facebook credentials must never be sent to the backend**, therefore do the upload to Facebook on client side using Facebook SDK.

Doing it from client side also save you the infrastructure cost on the backend.

Comment: why would you send user credentials to the backend anyway? of course you should never do that, you can just send an access token from the js sdk - or just do that server side. i do agree that doing stuff on the client would save infrastructure cost on the backend though.

Comment: @luschn Should it be better according to you to do everything from the client?

Comment: it depends...see my answer